InvisibleSmartCaptcha не могу получить новый токен
В документации Yandex Smart Captcha сброс токена предлагается реализовать сменой key элемента, однако:
const YandexInvisibleSmartCaptcha = () => {
  const [resetCaptcha, setResetCaptcha] = useState(0);
  const handleCaptchaReset = () => setResetCaptcha((i) => i + 1);
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  console.log(token);
  
  return (
    <>
      <InvisibleSmartCaptcha
        key={resetCaptcha}
        sitekey={sitekey}
        onSuccess={setToken}
      />
      <button onClick={handleCaptchaReset}>rest</button>
    </>
  );
};

возвращает тот же токен.
Проблема возникает, когда необходимо отправить ту же форму повторно. Что странно, токен судя по всему не меняется даже после обновления страницы. Однако, все капчи на сайте генерят тот же токен, и отправляются первый раз и по очереди нормально.
Может кто-то в курсе, как это должно работать для повторной отправки формы
